# GIT branching - can we survive with just a master?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am pretty new to GIT and and am looking for ways to manage source code across our 4 environments, between a distributed development teams working on bugfixes and new development, while keeping it as lean and straightforward as possible. we have two sprint teams working on same source code.

Having said that, can there be any issues with having only one master branch across environments so that we dont have to deal with merging code between different branches? I have not seen many example models with just one master, hence not sure how it will turn out.

Thanks.

Comment: if you mean only having the master branch and *no other branches*, it won't not work but you're not making use of one of git's major advantages, e.g. the ability to have in progress code. typically, people use the master branch for production ready code, not for development

Comment: On your remote, you can have 1 master branch, but it should not be done on a development system.  It will work OK until the minute you need to handle a more pressing issue, and a developer has to toss out work.  It is best to read more about git: https://git-scm.com/doc.  Don't be afraid of merge conflicts and merging.

Comment: There is no reason not to use branches with Git. If you're trying to avoid branches, you probably aren't using Git as it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of *branch names* is largely irrelevant.  You will have to deal with merging code regardless of how many branch names you have—merging is merely a byproduct of parallel work, where person A works on the the code (in A's copy of the repository) while person B also works on the code (in B's copy of the repository).  At some point *someone*—A, B, a third person, or some collection of all of these—must then work together to *combine* the work done by both A and B.

This combining is actually *easier* if you provide branch names for each bit of parallel work, because otherwise the names you have are raw Git hash IDs, which appear to be entirely random and are totally unsuited for human communication.  Do not fear branch names: they are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> can there be any issues with having only one master branch across environments so that we dont have to deal with merging code between different branches

You *can* work with only one branch, but that will not prevent merges to occur - at least when there is more than one developer contributing to the code. In fact you will find yourself merging much *more often* when everybody works on the same branch, say `master`, because every time you want to `push`, you first must integrate upstream changes. Whenever you say `git pull` to get your coworker's contributions into your working branch, git is effectively doing a `fetch` followed by a `merge`.

However, if there is at least one branch for every developer (or feature that is worked on), then each developer pushes to his/her own branch and decides when to merge. This is often much more convenient than to be forced to merge at times when you are not prepared to.

Git is very good at merging. You don't have to fear it.

**Summary:** yes, you can work with only `master`, but it will not make your life easier and I don't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

> *Having said that, can there be any issues with having only one master branch across environments so that we dont have to deal with merging code between different branches? I have not seen many example models with just one master, hence not sure how it will turn out.*

You haven't seen much about that because it throws away one of the strengths of Git, cheap branches and easy merges. You'll still be merging because `push` and `pull` will have to merge your local master with the remote master, but with everyone pushing and pulling to `master` whenever they feel like it everyone's work will get all mixed together and `master` will become a mess.

But you're on the right track. Instead of avoiding branches, you want to ***avoid long running branches***. No `develop` or `qa` branches. Having `master` as your single long running branch is a good workflow.

The trick is to ***never commit directly to master***. Instead you always want to be working in ***short lived "feature branches"*** which get merged into `master`. A feature branch is, from the name, for a single well specified feature (or bug). All work and QA for that feature happens on the feature branch. Once it's complete it is merged into `master`. `master` can be pushed straight into production, or you can tag specific releases.

This keeps `master` always in good shape to be worked off of and released from. It keeps work-in-progress clearly separated from `master` avoiding mistakenly putting broken code into `master`. It slows down how often `master` changes making it easier for everyone to coordinate. And it allows you to work on many features at the same time while keeping them all clearly separated.

The trick to keeping it simple and avoiding complicated merges is to always keep your branch on the latest `master` using `rebase`.

The basic workflow looks like this...

1. Bring your `master` up to date: `git checkout master; git pull --rebase`
2. Make and checkout a feature branch for your feature: `git checkout -b issue/#123`
3. Edit, work, and commit to your feature branch.
4. Periodically keep up to date with `master`.

   1. Bring your `master` up to date.
   2. Rewrite your work on top of `master`: `git checkout issue/#123; git rebase master`
5. When your work is finished, tested, gone through QA, etc...

   1. Bring your `master` up to date.
   2. Rewrite your work on top of `master`.
   3. Test your branch last time. This will be exactly the same code as after the merge because there's nothing to merge.
   4. Merge it into `master`. This merges changes nothing, you're already up to date, but its important for history: `git checkout master; git merge --no-ff issue/#123`
6. Delete your feature branch: `git branch -d issue/#123`
7. Goto 1

Note that updates are done with `rebase`. This avoids having a bunch of "bookkeeping" merges confusing the history. Instead with `rebase` you pretend as if your branch was written on the latest `master` all along. I recommend you set this in your `.gitconfig`

```
[pull]
        rebase = preserve
```

Then `git pull` is always done as a rebase, yet will preserve branches. This is completely safe.

The final real merge is done with `--no-ff` (no fast-forward) to guarantee the merge is done so the branch is retained in the history. The merge commit is also a place to write what the branch was about and provide a link to the issue it resolved.

The result is a history that looks like this:

```
                            J - K - L [issue/#123]
                           /
A ---------- E ---------- I [master]
 \         /  \         /
  B - C - D    F - G - H
```

That's two completed features `B - C - D` and `F - G - H`, and one open feature branch `J - K - L`. The branches are still there for archeological purposes, "feature bubbles", so future developers know that B - C - D were done as a unit and can reference the merge commit E for more information. And despite all the branching history is linear; `git log` will report commits in the correct order.

This is more work than simply committing to `master`, but it results in a clean, simple history, a high quality `master` to base your work on, and avoids developers crashing into each other. Version control is a tool, like your editor or shell, and it takes a bit of effort to use it effectively.